# Why is the Quran said to be the most beautiful Arabic literature?

Tags: religion, arabic-language, koran

Various sites on the Internet claim that the Quran is the most beautiful book written in the Arabic language, e.g. on [Blogspot](https://alhadithandislamicstudies.blogspot.com/2014/04/the-meaning-of-word-quran.html) and a chapter from the course [Keane World Religions on Course Hero](https://www.coursehero.com/file/8294904/Islam-Notes/).

The core of my question is: is it that Quran really has the most beautiful Arabic, or is that people defined beauty using the language in the Quran? Can this claim about the Quran be defended on the basis of its literary features?

Comment: Could you specify *who* in particular says the Quran is the most beautiful Arabic literature? Part of the reasoning might simply be religious belief: if that particular book is the word of God, it makes sense for it to be more beautiful than other texts written without divine aid. Have non-Islamic scholars, or non-religious experts in Arabic literature, said this too?

Comment: I unfortunately do not remember the source. I do remember, however, that there were a Spanish scholar some time during 711 and 1400s AD that said he will try to write a page of Arabic that is as beautiful as the Quran to show others that it is doable. He was targeting the statement that, because Quran is so beautifully written, it cannot possibly be written by human and thus must be divinely inspired.

Comment: My hunch would be that many religions claim their holy text is the most beautifully written.

Comment: The source for the claim seems to be the Quran itself. In [2:23-24](https://www.clearquran.com/002.html) it says: *And if you are in doubt about what We have revealed to Our servant, then produce a chapter like these, and call your witnesses apart from God, if you are truthful. But if you do not—and you will not—then beware the Fire whose fuel is people and stones, prepared for the disbelievers.*

Comment: @Alex thanks much for the reference!

Comment: @JLi You’re welcome.

Comment: @Alex Could you please turn that into an answer? Comments aren't really intended for answering questions.

Comment: @Tsundoku I don’t think it answers the question as asked.